# Create multiple schema in one DB on heroku postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-2, heroku-postgres

I want to have two schemas(except public) in a pgsql database on heroku. On local I have done it like imported the data to public schema and renamed it to the name of my choice. In the similar manner i created two schema under one DB and connected it to a rails application using

```
search_schema_path: 'schema1, schema2'
```

Now I want to do the same on heroku and tried the same procedure. But it seems that, rails can not find tables from the DB. I am getting the error relationship "delayed_jobs" does not exists. Please suggest me how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

When your Rails app is deployed on Heroku, an automatically generated `database.yml` over-writes your applications `database.yml`, which is dropping your `schema_search_path` setting, reseting it to `public`.

You can add an initializer that reset the value after load.  For example, `config/initializers/postgres_schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = 'schema1, schema2'
```

You'll need to be careful to set this anywhere you're re-connecting or re-setting.